# Unable to Dynamically Render Django images on templates

Tags: python, django

So I've been trying to get the images uploaded through admin interface to render on a template but for some odd reason it just wont render the images. It renders any other type of data but NOT IMAGES.

From Settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

From appvew.py:

```
class ProjectsListView(ListView):
    model = Projects
    context_object_name = 'projects'
    template_name = 'myportfolio/portfolio.html'
```

appurls.py:

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('home/', views.ProjectsListView.as_view()),
    # path('projects/', )
]
```

html template:

```
  {% load static %}
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1><p>This is my portfolio</p></h1>
    
    {% for project in projects %}
    <img src="{{project.screenshot}}" alt="No image found">
    
    {% endfor %}
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Error message on the terminal:

Not Found: /portfolio/home/projects/images/shutterstock_253580635_square.jpg
Not Found: /portfolio/home/projects/images/mountains.jpg
[25/Mar/2022 14:16:06] ←[33m"GET /portfolio/home/projects/images/shutterstock_253580635_square.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2560←[0m
[25/Mar/2022 14:16:06] ←[33m"GET /portfolio/home/projects/images/mountains.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2500←[0m

output :( :[image: This is what the outut looks like]

I verified an old project of mine with pretty much the same set up and it works. This one on the other hand, only renders the name of the objects on other properties but not the images

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<img src="{{project.screenshot.url}}" alt="No image found">
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/

Comment: WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  WOW Spent hours on this and couldn't get it to work! Many thanks, really!

Comment: Can you please explain why "url" has to be added at the end? I don't remember ever using it and it seemed to work by simple passing the name of the object... am confused, but still appreciate the solution!

Comment: @MonkBR https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/ refer this

Comment: @Monk BR If this answer is helpful, you can upvote and accept it.